# Comparing conjugacy classes in central extensions

Tags: group-theory, central-extensions

Let $G$ be a group containing a finite central subgroup $Z$. Considering the conjugation action of $G$ on $G/Z$, define the stabilizer subgroups $$\operatorname{Stab}_G(gZ) = \{h \in G\colon hgh^{-1} = gz\text{ for some }z \in Z\}\,.$$ These contain the centralizers $C_G(g)$, but *a priori* they may differ. My question is the following:

**Question** If the index $|G\colon \operatorname{Stab}_G(gZ)|$ is finite, can the index $|\operatorname{Stab}_G(gZ)\colon C_G(g)|$ be infinite?

In other words, if $g \in G$ is such that the conjugacy class of $gZ$ is finite in $G/Z$, can the conjugacy class of $g$ in $G$ be infinite?

Comment: I think there might be an embedding of the conj. class of g into the Cartesian product of $Z$ with the conjugacy class of $gZ$: first choose $g \in T_0$ a set of representatives in $G$ of the conj. classes of $G/Z$, and for each $t \in T_0$ fix a transversal $S_t$ of $G/\operatorname{Stab}(tZ)$. Conjugating $t$ by all the elements of $S_t$ gives us a transversal $T$ of the quotient. Now, write any conjugate $rgr^{-1}$ uniquely as $usgs^{-1}$ with $s \in S_g$. This should give the desired embedding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Denote by $C$ the conjugacy class of $g$ and by $D$ the class of $gZ$. Then, consider the function
$$f \colon C \to D$$
defined by $f(h) = hZ$. We have that $f^{-1}(hZ) = \{k \in C \colon k = hz,\text{ for some }z \in Z\}$, therefore, the cardinality of any fiber is less than or equal to $|Z|$. Since $D$ and $Z$ are finite, we conclude that
\begin{align*}
|C| & = \bigg|\bigcup_{hZ \in D} f^{-1}(hZ)\bigg| \\ & \leq |D|\cdot|Z|
\end{align*}
and, therefore, the conjugacy class of $g$ is finite.